# Sweep Between Two Curves to Create Mesh

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I need to create a shape where the bottom is a circle and the top is a square, with a perfect transition from top to bottom.

In Cinema 4D and Fusion 360 this is very simple, you just create two curves and then tell one to sweep to meet the other.  I'm assuming there is a similar way to do this with Blender but I can't seem to find it.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/d627p2ukca0mumxjxru2h/Sweep-Curves-How.blend?rlkey=khhjr099ul57990y94yv2vkuo&dl=0)

[image]

Comment: i'm not sure this is possible with curves, it is possible with mesh as shown by Harry

Comment: You can try Geometry nodes  ... search for "loft" techniques ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278462/create-mesh-from-four-curves-loft/278476#278476

Comment: @moonboots it may be possible with curve using python

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/normalize-a-spline https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122230/lofting-can-i-copy-a-shape-keyed-mesh-for-each-frame-of-its-animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138901/loft-tool-in-blender-2-8/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278462/create-mesh-from-four-curves-loft/

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I did do research thank you but all of the solutions I found were mostly pertaining to mesh loops or add-ons (and were also pre v3), so I hoped that dusting off the topic might be enlightening.  Guess not, but I do appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: @GlenCandle: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278462/create-mesh-from-four-curves-loft/ -> this solution should fit to your question. AN (animation nodes) is a free (!) great add-on, which also today is in a lot of areas much more powerful than geometry nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Add a plane and subdivide it 7 times. Add a circle with 32 vertices. Join both objects and select all vertices then *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*

[image]

Comment: Not possible with curves. But by the way, you can add the circle in _Edit Mode_, no need to create two objects and join them ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes i just mentioned it explicitly in case some new users are not aware of that :D

Comment: New users will probably wonder how adding and subdividing a plane will give them just a square edge loop without any faces... and probably not know how exactly they should join both objects... just my experience over the years when I'm not explicitly mention each single step. Sorry, being sarcastic again ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hahaha yes you actually have good points! well i hope the gif will make it easy enough to understand XD

Comment: I guess Glen is already experienced enough to get it, complete newbies probably not ;) Unfortunately still no solution for his problem... I suppose it can only be done in _Geometry Nodes_.

Comment: Thanks @HarryMcKenzie.  I am working on a product design and I need to keep the shape dynamic, so a mesh isn't a solution for me, but I do appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: @GlenCandle can it be a mesh if it's generated via python? or does it need to be a curve?

Comment: That's a great question @HarryMcKenzie but sadly I don't know python so I don't think that would be comfortable for me

Comment: @GlenCandle it's actually easy. All I need to know is the exact requirement like your input parameters (i.e. square size & position, circle radius & position, etc), then i'll write you a script and all you have to do is paste it into Blender's Text Editor and execute the script. the input parameters can then also be easily changed in the script. It's easy, you don't need to know a alot of technicals :)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie that is a very generous offer, thank you.  I've actually decided to design the parts in Fusion 360 instead, and then send STL's back to Blender for renderings. Cheers!