# How to make UV loft like 3ds Max in Blender using curves?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am try to make a car Body using the technique like UV loft in 3ds Max.

How to apply this technique in  Blender using curves or closer to this technique? I have seen this technique in a Blender tutorial, but I forgot about it.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138901/loft-tool-in-blender-2-8/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278462/create-mesh-from-four-curves-loft https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301152/how-could-a-loft-object-be-closed

Answer (score 12):

In Blender 2.68+ there is this built-in mesh tool *Grid Fill*.

Access from the *Face Menu > Grid Fill*.

It expects a matching number of vertex on each opposing loop.

[image: grid fille example]
[image: grid fille example]

Comment: Useful, but seems overly simplistic, limited to two curves with the same number of vertices. Source code is very tersely documented - no improvements in sight?

Comment: Added support for non-uniform grids: https://developer.blender.org/rBd573bb4f661ae8195d99193dda41b03821df3677

Answer (score 8):

**I am not sure about UV lofting**.. but there is an addon now bundled with Blender called *[Curve Tools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Curve_Tools)*. *It might not be as powerful as Max's or exactly what you want but it might suit your current needs.*

You can add several curves to the scene and under *Curve Tools* in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel, hit *Loft*. The wiki page has some useful information and videos if you need a quick place to start.

[image]
<sub>(source: [picasion.com](http://i.picasion.com/pic70/8023db1bfa09b7bd53e52808de94871e.gif))</sub>

Once you are finished, a mesh is made separate from the curves so you can continue editing or tweaking them.

A reminder, this isn't *UV* lofting but it can be a solution nonetheless. One obvious limitation that you might notice is you have to use several curves as opposed to one comprised of several segments.

---

<sup>*nb:* I had originally written up an answer for this elsewhere but since it wasn't what OP intended or wanted at the time, I think it can be put here as a separate possible solution to your question, see the other post [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines).</sup>

Comment: This is a U loft, UV lofts are created from several curves spanning two dimensions.

Comment: @Aldrik I never said it was, I merely offered it. I am also sure OP might have phrased their title not fully according to what he/she wanted. It is true this is limited but it can be used for simpler lofting.

Answer (score 5):

Blender's limited NURBS don't currently support this feature. The following addon adds similar but limited functionality.

## [Curve Tools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Curve_Tools)

Once installed and enabled. It's accessed via the "Tool Shelf" (<kbd>T</kbd> to toggle).

> Birail between 3 curves:
>
> -The order in which we select the curves and its direction its important to make this work right.
>   -First select the profile and then the 2 paths to create the birail.

[image: Three curves and Tool Shelf showing the Curve Tools] [image: Generated mesh]

You can see this is demonstrated in the [introduction video](http://vimeo.com/24868827#t=195).