# Turning a ring of vertices into a plane

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've got a ring of vertices. How can I add an edge from a newly added centre vertex, to every other vertex in the mesh (and then add faces between all of the new edges)?

[image]

Comment: Do you definitely want it this way or can the plane can come from any method?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what I want.. I need to be able to map an image onto it though.

Comment: ok, I have an idea of something that might work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not easy to extrude a single vertex multiple times to fit several others manually as you described it in your question, even using automated methods… [gandalf3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1660/12)'s method is the best way to do it if you want it that way. However, based on your comment above, I think these ways might be better… depending on how your mesh is set up.

1. Use [BMesh](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh)! Just hit <kbd>F</kbd> and fill the thing, this will create an [ngon](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/07/11/So-whats-an-ngon-anyways.aspx)[image]
2. [Grid Fill](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1528/12) *(introduced in 2.68)*, if your mesh has the same number of vertices along two opposite edgeloops of a closed mesh and the same number on the other sides, you can use this to fill it.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: I'm still on Blender 2.62, so will have to wait until an upgrade before I can try this.

Comment: @ajwood you should upgrade to 2.63 at least, stop torturing yourself with archaic modeling tools.. [look to the future](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2013/06/blender-roadmap-2-7-2-8-and-beyond/) man! :)

Comment: I'm just relying on the Ubuntu repository.. I'll upgrade manually though.

Comment: @ajwood http://askubuntu.com/questions/169542/how-do-i-install-the-latest-blender-3d-builds-from-a-ppa

Answer (score 6):

## Another method to create a face with a vertex at the centre.

1. Select your vertices:
   [image: select vertices]
2. *Make Face* <kbd>F</kbd>, this'll create a ngon:
   [image: make face]
3. *Poke Faces* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, this'll create a single vertex at the centre:
   [image: poke mesh]

Answer (score 1):

Method one:

- Deleting the center vertex, <kbd>A</kbd> select all, 
  <kbd>E</kbd> extrude,

  [image]

  then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge at center*.

  [image]

  Extruding then scaling to zero would also work. (either with *Auto-Merge Editing* enabled or *Remove Doubles* afterwards)

Method two:

- Using the *Fill* tool.
  Select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

  [image]

  Note that this is with the *Beauty*  [image]option **off**

  With *Beauty* **on**:

  [image]

Comment: I think the original method you posted that answered the question as OP asked it was ok, mine complimented it and merely offered alternatives. This updated one with the cross-referencing and inclusion is a bit confusing..

Comment: @iKlsR Removed the bmesh bit that was the same as yours. BTW, it's thanks to your selecting the *Fill* tool instead of *Make edges and Faces* that I even thought of *Fill*.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

since you have dispensed with the limitation that there should be a central vertex connecting them all (this would be bad for more extreme concave polygon shapes anyway). Because you are writing a script anyway, example code ([bmesh.ops.edgenet_fill](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_64_9/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.edgenet_fill)) ?

```
import bpy, bmesh

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
edges = [edge for edge in bm.edges if edge.select]

bmesh.ops.edgenet_fill(bm, edges=edges)

# recalculate n-gon tessellation and update viewport.
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

[image]