# Connecting two curves with same number of vertices

Tags: extrude, bezier-curves, bevel

I'm looking to connect two curves. One duplicated from the other and then modified. They have the same number of vertices. While a more broad question than this example, I'm trying to connect a top and bottom curve to define a curtain. 
[image]

I know that I can convert the curves to meshes and then do the time consuming task of connecting the vertices into faces. I'm looking for a faster work flow where I can extrude or bevel from one curve to the other. TIA

Comment: Related or even a duplicate (?): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to go to mesh there is a pretty fast method.

1. With both curved selected <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join these two Curves into one object.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> >> <kbd>M</kbd> to convert the curves to a mesh.
3. <kbd>TAB</kbd> - to enter edit mode.
4. <kbd>A</kbd> - to select all vertices.
5. <kbd>W</kbd> >> <kbd>E</kbd> - to perform the **Bridge Edge Loops** command.
6. <kbd>TAB</kbd> - To go back to Object Mode and enjoy your curtains.

Comment: And,  to augment just a bit what Rick wrote, if you need to you can add a step 7, which is a repeat of step 2, except that the M-key is replaced by the C-key, to convert  a mesh back to a curve.