# I can't bridge/loft these vertices

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to bridge/loft these 3 shapes and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Hello :). *Edge > Bridge edge loops* might work better in this case. There's a whole thread [concerning bridge/loft tools in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/138901/78972)

Comment: i try it this thread ,but not working.

Comment: in the second picture i do it all the shapes from add-

Comment: Hello :). You have to do it one by one. Select two loops > bridge. Select another two loops > bridge. Selecting multiple won't work.

Comment: It appears as though your loops are separate objects. First in object mode select both objects then join them <ctrl> J. Next return to edit mode. Select 2 loops at a time, then use the edge> Bridge edge loops as JACHYM MICHAL mentioned above.

Comment: thanks all. the join command was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create faces or vertices that are shared across different objects. **All vertices, edges and faces need to be part of the same object**.

[image]

Select all of the circles, join them into a single object (<kbd>shift</kbd> select the objects to be joinede and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>). Once all vertices belong to a single object then you can use the bridge edge loops tool.

[image]

Comment: thanks cegaton.when the JOIN is missing is not working.now i writed to myself too.

Comment: The shortcut is CTRL + J

Comment: correct. i do it already .thanks.

Comment: Read also https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers