# Cannot use J, F or Bridge in Edit Mode in Blender 3.3.0 - Invalid Selection Order

Tags: modeling

Simple scene with two cubes in *Edit mode*. In v3.3.0, I have to use Control to select both cubes. I can then use shift to select two vertices/faces/edges. I want to join, create face and or bridge the gap between the cubes.  If I use  <kbd>J</kbd>,  <kbd>F</kbd> or *Loop Tools > Bridge*, I get *Invalid Selection Error*.

What is happening? This never happened in previous editions.

I use a MacBook Pro mid-2012 Retina running OS Catalina

Comment: If the 2 cubes are 2 separate objects, you can't join any vertices between their meshes, you first need to join them with Ctrl J to make one unique object

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162944/i-cant-bridge-loft-these-vertices