# How to extrude from a square shape to a circle shape?

Tags: modeling

[image]

This is roughly the shape I want to make but in 3D. I want to extrude some shape, e.g. a plane, into a circle. I tried using the Curves to Mesh plugin but it didn't work for me because I had an older version which doesn't have a "sweep to mesh" option.

Comment: Activate the loop tools addon, extrude, subdivide, select edge, right click, looptools, circle, smooth in between geometry.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/138939/35559)

Comment: Also [How can I model a bottle with triangular base and circular top? (Nail Polish Bottle)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/228436/60486)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the tool you want is bridge edge loops, but you may have to subdivide the square loop first, so it has the same number of vertices as the circle loop.