# Merge Two Elements seamlessly

Tags: modeling

Hey so Im trying to experiment with two meshes. I have a cylinder and a prism stacked on top of each other. How would I organically and seamlessly connect the two.

Caution: Blender Newbie... Might not understand everything.
Cheers

[image]

Comment: If you can arrange for the vertex-counts in the perimeters to be the same, _Bridge Edge Loops_  (Blend Surface) will do it. See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/138939/35559)

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot...