# Double curvature surface from curves generated with geometry node

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, remesh

I'm new to blender and I was trying to follow a tutorial of the bosjes chapel in YT with destructive modeling, and thought to myself...Let's try to do this with geonodes!!!
So the roof of the chapel is a double curvature surface, I got all the curves that define the roof but I cannot seem to remesh it to have the correct surface.

EDIT: Here the .blend

[image]

Thank you!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can share your file by going to https://blend-exchange.com/ and following the instructions there.

Comment: Thank you John!

Comment: can u please add an image how it should look like? what's your problem now, building faces?

Comment: Thanx Chris! I updated the first post.

Answer (score 2):

So i used the great solution vklidu provided here:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/278476/86978

and i just made a node group out of his solution, made a 3rd curve, and the result was this:

[image]

Node tree:

[image]

node group:

[image]

of course you can choose whatever splines/curves you want, just adapt them to your needs.

[image]

Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris! going to try this right away!

Comment: Ok. So I gave this a try, this solution is a simple curvature surface , although in a way you can control the double curvature like shown in the gif, it is not based in a perpendicular curve that passes from the start curve and the end curve. I need to drive the surface by 4 control curves as shown in the image below. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cY8x.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cY8x.jpg)