# How to make sphere peeling animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, bezier-curves

I need to make an animation of peeling off the shells of an egg shaped object.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJaVsMutjdQ&t=15s

I need to do the animation in this sample video, but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Please try to avoid link-only references.. they can be broken and lost to the archive, and may be tedious for the good folks of BSE to follow.

Comment: a bit complex: i hope you're an expert at blender.  Perhaps I see a copy of the egg shape that is slightly larger in scale to cover the egg;  cloth physics; a sewing seam vertex group with decreasing vertex weights top to bottom;  a use of some Vertex Weight Edit modifier to slowly unzip the tears; some forces that help to curl (magnetism perhaps).  wow.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a perhaps too clean GN approach.. but in my experience, it's easier to mess up something that's too clean, than the other way round. There are lot of nodes and sub-groups in the final modifier, so this answer will just settle for a summary of the method; if you download the .blend, you can assign the subgroups independently, to see what they do.

Starting with a curve half-profile of the egg, such as you might *Screw* to the solid, the first step is a 'Curl Curve':

[image]

.. which sticks an aligned, fixed-length *Curve Primitive > Spiral* on to the end of the egg profile, as it's being trimmed. It then trims the combined curve from the other end, so the overall length is preserved. The original profile's XY radius is stored on the curled curve.

The next step is to rotate the points of duplicates of the curled curve in such a way as to fully span 1 segment of the solid egg, while preserving the stored original radius

[image]

And then the duplicates are lofted using the *Loft Curves* group from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/278577/35559) to make one segment, The segments are duplicated and rotated to encompass the solid, and their UV's wrangled to unify them and make texturing  possible.

[image]

Currently, the final group exposes U and V resolutions in the geometry, the number of segments, and the degree to which the wrapping is unfurled.

With this sort of result:

[image]

[image]