# Blend 2 cylinders with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to blend 2 cylinders perpendicular into each other.
The smaller cylinder should follow exactly the curvature of the bigger base cylinder.

I achieved this already with the help of the Raycast node.

[image: Cylider blending with geometry nodes]

Thats a good beginning but I additionally would like to let the curvature fade out stepwise. Like I scribbled here:

[image: How it should be]

Can you advise me how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The *Loft Curves* GN group described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/278577/35559) interpolates between profiles naturally, so to achieve your purpose, you can use it to construct your base-projected cylinder:

[image]

To loft cyclic curves with this group, they must be split, and re-merged after conversion to mesh, to preserve the UV coordinates of face-corners in the named attribute `uv_map`

[image]

I haven't  exposed all parameters to the interface in this example, or gone very far wrangling UV's in a way that might suit you.. if you need more refinement,  call back, and I'll do my best.

[image]

Comment: Wow,this is great! Thank you very much.