# selecting geo node extrusion to loft to a 2nd mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, stl, loft

I have a geonodes mesh and an imported .stl mesh and want to connect both meshes so they form a manifold body later for 3d printing.

when working with nodes I cant select the voronoid edge created in geonodes to use as guide curve along the loft should happen (see blue edges) anyone has an idea how to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/278577/35559) will help .. it depends a bit on the exact end effect you want.. do you really mean you imported the cuboid as an STL, or is there something more elaborate going on?

Comment: its a bit more complicated, the "wall" is just an example. I have a organic shaped body, one of the face i want to procedurally pattern like the voronoi pattern seen in the post, since the transition between the pattern and the organic shape wont be curvature continues with the unpatterned surface, i was thinking on removing some faces and loft between the 2 open edges (as shown here) with constraints eg. 1 point of the spline attached to my curved surface with geometric constrains(lets see if blender can do that somehow) the other following the open edge of the voronoi pattern