How to make separate curves to have the same tangent on their points
I have individual Bezier curves that are needed to create the road.  There are meshes of different lengths - these are sections of the road that can have different curvature of turns and elevation heights. These meshes are using Curve modifier and they are connected to each other. The problem - the ends of the curves have different tangents (tilt, normals), as a result - the sections of the road do not join correctly, perhaps the problem is that the handles for each curve at the connection points have different angles. How can I force these individual curves to have the same tangents at their points of contact?  I'm not good at writing scripts, but maybe it's possible to do this using a script or something else?



Desired result

I wonder if some variation on https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/278577/35559 would work for you

I'll look at it, thanks
