# Loft or extrude between separate mesh surfaces

Tags: modeling, extrude

This is my first post so please be easy on me. I'm trying to make an F-16 in blender for 3D printing. The tutorials on Youtube gave me a model with many open surfaces so it wouldn't slice. So instead im trying to create a model similar to how I would in SolidWorks, by lofting/extruding cross-sections to create the body. [image]
So I have 4 mesh's at separate locations that have the cross-section traced out. I tried extruding the first into the second, and also bridging edge loops with no luck(guessing since not even amount of vertices?). Is it possible to do what I'm after in blender? I couldn't find any recent threads with a similar question.

Thank you very much for your time

[image][image]

Comment: just search here for loft + curves and you will find several answers -> and yes, you can turn mesh into curves

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot, Thanks!

Comment: Although you can loft curves with GN, for a model with good topology. I don't think there's much choice but to count vertices in related  segments to match. The 'Statistics' overlay, and  the shipped add-on _Loop Tools_ > _Space_  and > _Relax_ will be your freinds.

Comment: Once you'll have the same number of vertices on each mesh, you can enable the LoopTools addon, select all the meshes and right click > LoopTools > Loft

Comment: If you've got two seperate mesh objects that you want to join with faces you'll have to make them into a single object first using Ctrl-J in Object mode before you can Loft them or join edges between the two objects.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138901/loft-tool-in-blender-2-8/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278462/create-mesh-from-four-curves-loft https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301152/how-could-a-loft-object-be-closed

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?