# Can Geometry nodes recreate the shape based on three curves?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was wondering if the task is even possible in GN. Tried to search for something similar, but no luck. Perhaps I don't know how to formulate the request

So basically, is it possible to recreate a similar mesh in GN using three curves as inputs? (curves are highlighted on screenshot) Which way I shall be looking? [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278462/create-mesh-from-four-curves-loft https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301152/how-could-a-loft-object-be-closed