Making a fan duct
Trying to design my own fan duct for my 3D printer, and
I followed this guide and got a pretty decent result. It basically works the way I want it to, except for that I want to be able to narrow down the duct gradually towards the end. Any ideas?




Hello do you have a reference image of the object you want to achieve?

@moonboots If you see in the last image on the post, that's around something I'm trying to achieve, just making the end more narrow to clear the print surface and to direct airflow better. Here is an example of a typical duct shape I want where it narrows towards the end

what does it give if you select the bottom, activate the Proportional Editing, and move it up on Z?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale

It looks like you want the duct to squeeze into a semi circle by the end?

The bezier curve? It just moves the end of the tube up and down without deforming it, even with proportional editing activated @moonboots

Sort of, I want to deform the tube and make it more narrow towards the end. Basically if I had the ability to create each end, then use the bezier curve to generate a tube that connects both ends, that would be perfect. @TheLabCat

This looks very informative, and some of the stuff in there might be exactly what I want. I need to test it out and see, thank you. @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos simply doing the alt+s on the bezier curve does almost exactly what I want it to, except I would really like to be able to scale the circle down on just one axis to make it more into an oval. Would this be possible? It's looking good though :]

Look into lofting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138901/loft-tool-in-blender-2-8/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278462/create-mesh-from-four-curves-loft https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301152/how-could-a-loft-object-be-closed If an answer helps you don't forget to upvote the post that helped you.

Thank you @DuarteFarrajotaRamos
