# Join 2 surfaces with a path defined by 2 bezier curves

Tags: bezier-curves

I want to join 2 surfaces ( [1] & [3] ) with the top path defined by the Bezier curve[4] and the bottom defined by the Bezier curve[2]. See the image for reference.

[image]

I don't know if I described my issue exactly, but I want my 3d surface to be within the given 4 boundaries. Please help me with the steps or provide any reference related to this issue.

blender file:[image]

Comment: Yea added the file. 
Also, Bridge edge loops doesn't seem to work .

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138901/loft-tool-in-blender-2-8 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278462/create-mesh-from-four-curves-loft

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Comment: Yes indeed a duplicate question. You can easily do it with *Face > Grid Fill*. Just convert all to mesh then join them together and make sure the vertices are joined. then make sure both sides have the same number of vertices https://snipboard.io/CjFshT.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I couldn't find the word that described this step ('loft') which limited my research. And yeah its a duplicate question, apologies.

Comment: @fasith i don't even know what "loft" means haha