# Bridge Edge Loops with Curve

Tags: bezier-curves

Ultimately, I want to make mirrored ribbons, wider at the bottom/furthest from the bow-knot. I created one mirrored bezier curve and rotated its duplicate (with the 3D cursor) at one end of the curve; I then made another curve (random shape for demonstration purposes) spanning the maximum width between what will be the sides of each ribbon. Is there a way to bridge the side-of-ribbon edge loops with the third curve, rather than the shortest path between points? Or is there a way to vary the extrusion width of ribbons generated using [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oV_rqFlKi_I) prior to converting to mesh (after which I know I could use proportional scaling)? Thanks!

[image: dia1][image: dia2]

Comment: Have you watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4F6Q6h2-ao ?

Comment: I had not, until you showed it to me. It'll certainly come in handy on other projects, but not for what I'm looking for right now. Thank you though!

Comment: (Revised pictures for hopeful clarity.)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138901 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122230

Comment: Can't post as answer; I'll just leave this here for now. Took me a while to figure out where the loft tool was hiding in v2.90 (Glorfindel's answer at question #1503 gave me the hint I needed). It's under Edit > Surfaces > Loft in the N menu on Object Mode, and I was able to use the two longer curves to get a good result.